# How can I create a pandas pivot table showing the percentage of one of three options?

Tags: python, pandas

I have sports data of the following structure:

```
season, country, league, hometeam, awayteam, status
```

The status can be H, or D or A

I want to create a pivot table for each season, country and league showing the H as percentage of the total matches.

```
import pandas as pd

grouped_success_rate = df_data.groupby(["Season", "Country", "League"])

homewins_per_league = grouped_success_rate.apply(lambda x: x[(x["STATUS"] == "H")].shape[0]).unstack("Season")
homewins_per_league.fillna(0, inplace=True)
homewins_per_league["TOTAL"] = homewins_per_league.apply(lambda x: sum(x), axis=1)

total_matches_per_league = grouped_success_rate.apply(lambda x: len(x["STATUS"])).unstack("Season")
total_matches_per_league.fillna(0, inplace=True)
total_matches_per_league["TOTAL"] = total_matches_per_league.apply(lambda x: sum(x), axis=1)

homewins_rate_per_league = (homewins_per_league / total_matches_per_league).applymap(lambda x: round(x, 3))
```

As you can see I group my dataframe, but then I have to create a separate dataframe for a specific option and for the total. Is there a way to do it without creating the two dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add a column to the DataFrame first:

```
df_data['is_H'] = df_data['Status'] == 'H'
df_data.groupby(["Season", "Country", "League"])['is_H'].mean()
```